# Angular not defined and Unexpected token: <

Tags: angularjs, model-view-controller, angular-material

I'm a bit confused at *what* I need to include *where* in my new Angular Material project, after looking at a few references.

I'm getting these errors:
[image: Angular Errors 1]

And here is the location of that last one:
[image: Angular Error 2]

Here are the relevant files:

**MainController.js**

```
/**
 * Created by jkl94 on 5/11/2017.
 */
var RhetoricChecker = angular.module('RhetoricChecker.controllers', ['ngMaterial']);

RhetoricChecker.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $timeout, $mdSidenav, $log){

});
```

**main.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angular_material/1.1.0/angular-material.min.css">
    <title>Welcome to RhetoricChecker!</title>
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="MainCtrl" layout="column" style="height:500px;" ng-cloak>

    <section layout="row">
        <md-sidenav class="md-sidenav-left" md-component-id="left" md-is-locked-open="$mdMedia('gt-md)" md-whiteframe="4">
            <md-toolbar class="md-theme-indigo">
                <h1 class="md-toolbar-tools">Sidenav Left</h1>
            </md-toolbar>
        </md-sidenav>
    </section>

    <h1>Welcome to RhetoricChecker!</h1>

    <!-- HTML STUFF -->


</div>

<!-- Angular Material requires Angular.js Libraries -->
<script src="./node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-aria/angular-aria.min.js"></script>
<script src="./node_modules/angular-messages/angular-messages.min.js"></script>

<!-- Angular Material Library -->
<script src="./node_modules/angular-material/angular-material.min.js"></script>
<script src="./controllers/MainController.js"></script>
<!-- Your application bootstrap  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
    /**
     * You must include the dependency on 'ngMaterial'
     */
    angular.module('RhetoricChecker.controllers', ['ngMaterial']);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

**server.js**

```
/**
 * Created by jkl94 on 5/11/2017.
 */

var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var routes = require('./routes');
routes(app);


app.listen(1337);
console.log("Now listening on port 1337");
```

I think this is just a matter of me not importing the right files in the right places, but for the life of me, I can't quite figure out what I'm missing.

Comment: Look at your network panel in the browser dev tools. The requests sent to download your JS files seem to get back HTML as a response. Your URLs are wrong, or your server is misconfigured.

Comment: You are defining the module `angular.module('RhetoricChecker.controllers', ['ngMaterial']);` twice. Once in MainController.js and once in the script immediately following. I can't say that will solve all your issues, but it is not helping your cause

Comment: @JBNizet you are correct, it is getting back an HTML response. I am unsure why, however.
When I copy the relative path to my angular.min.js it is:

/node_modules/angular/angular.min.js

This is exactly what I have, however. So what do you mean by "server is misconfigured?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem simply by switching all my my  imports to CDNs. Additionally, I used static file routing via express to change the location of my MainController.